# How accelerate time to serialPort.close(); currently 3 seconds

Tags: java, serial-port

In a serialPort polling program, I need to get a reply once per second, or so. However, I noticed in the log that the `serialPort.close();` method takes exactly 3 seconds to complete. Hence I need to wait 4 seconds before polling the port again.  Any ideas how to accelerate the port closing? Why is this so? Using RXTXcomm.jar rxtx-2.2pre1.

```
if (readBufferArray[numBytes-1] == ETXinHex   ){
       one =  one.substring(0,numBytes-1); one =  one + "]"; 
        logger.info("add ]");
        serialPort.close();   //takes 3 seconds !! to close!!
        logger.info("port closed ETX correctly received");
        portFound = false;
        logger.info("port Found false");

    }


  2013-12-21 11:22:20,227 [Thread-16] INFO  - add [
  2013-12-21 11:22:20,227 [Thread-16] INFO  - add ]
  2013-12-21 11:22:23,227 [Thread-16] INFO  - port closed ETX correctly received
  2013-12-21 11:22:23,227 [Thread-16] INFO  - port Found false
```

Comment: Why do you have to close the port between the polls?

Comment: I poll an external device every second. This is a server environment. with multiple users. A user could not access the port while it is locked by another user. If no other remedy is found I would have the server lock the port on bootup, read the value every second or less, store it on the server and share  this value  to all users with appropriate rights...

Comment: If you have multiple users using the same port what would they expect to read from it? Can you describe what you actually try to accomplish? What kind of byte stream from a serial port wold be interesting for multiple users to start reading at any time (where the order of the users does not matter)? The only one I can think of would be some kind of random number generator.

Comment: It is the current weight read on a weighbridge. The operator needs to read this, maybe a manager, or the driver?  My question is why does it take so long to just 'close' the port? I thought it would be a few machine cycles, ie at most a microsecond...

Comment: In case acceleration to close cannot be achieved other approaches need to be considered:One, eg, abandon handshake mode, and use a continuous mode where the values are continuously broadcasted on the port. These values shall be written to the database, and shared by users from there. Or open port, read values periodically, write to the database, and at session close, close port. Users access values on database.

Comment: Found solution: Abandoned RXTX, and replaced by jssc, in  
java-simple-serial-connector, where to find it: https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/       Solves everything

Comment: I am using setserial, and when getting the properties of the serial port   I get:   setserial -a /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
 Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
 closing_wait: none
 Flags: spd_normal skip_test
The closing_wait parameter was set to 3000 , that is exactly 3 sec. Updating it to none with setserial /dev/ttyS0 closing_wait none and also changing the /var/lib/setserial/autoserial.conf file did not bring any change to closing_wait when executing from java. Same 3 sec delay.

Comment: RXTX ignores setserial params settings, closing_wait set to none ignored by java. Remains at 3 sec.